# Operand can't be null in null check

Tags: flutter

I wanna check if `text2!` is `not null`, then set the `height` of the `SizedBox` to the value in `height` variable. If it's `null` then set the `height` of the `SizedBox` to `0`.

**Error:** Operand can't be null, so the condition is always true.

**Code**

```
double height = 10;

SizedBox(
            height: widget.text2! != null ? height : 0,
          ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `!` you say that `text2` is not null. Just omit the `!`.

```
SizedBox(height: widget.text2 != null ? height : 0,),
```

Comment: I put `!` to warn that it could be null as well. But flutter works in a different way than I think it seems, thanks for the answer, it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

The `!` operator in front of a nullable variable, forces such variable to be non-null. With that Dart takes a leap of faith, in which the developer takes responsibility about the nullability of the expression, runtime-wise.

By using `!` in that context, such comparison will always evaluate to `true`: you're ensuring the left-hand operand is `not null`, while the right one *is* `null`.

Removing the `!` will do the trick.